# How can I adjust the duration of each season?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-seasons

Is there any way to make certain seasons last longer than others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the game options you can specify the lengths of seasons in days (max being 28(?) days)

Comment: I looked at it on the options just then and it said that..thank you anyways

Comment: @XxMinecraftxGirlxX [Don't forget to accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)